# Deploy Shiny app that uses the scholar (Google Scholar) package?

Tags: r, shiny, google-scholar

I've seen several posts about this but in my ignorance cannot understand (1) if what I want to do is possible, and (2) if someone has solved it.

I am trying to deploy a Shiny app which uses the [scholar](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/scholar/index.html) package using shinyapps.io. A MWE of my app looks something like this:

```
library(shiny)
library(scholar)
library(dplyr)
library(ggplot2)

scholar_id <- "B7vSqZsAAAAJ"
auth <- get_profile(scholar_id)
pubs <- get_publications(id=scholar_id)
h_index <- auth$h_index

num_pubs <- nrow(pubs) # get number of publications
tot_cites <- sum(pubs$cites) # get total number of citations

# Get num. publications per year
pubYears <- data.frame("year" = pubs$year)
pubYears <- pubYears %>% group_by(year) %>% count(year)

# Get citations per year
citesYear <- get_citation_history(scholar_id)
citesYear$cumulativeCites <- cumsum(citesYear$cites)

# Publication summary
df <- data.frame("num_pubs" = num_pubs,
                 "h_index" = as.numeric(h_index),
                 "tot_cites" = as.numeric(tot_cites))

# Begin shiny app -----
ui <- fluidPage(
    ## Publication summary -----
    titlePanel("Article Publication Summary"),
    mainPanel(
        # Output table as first result
        tableOutput('table'),
        fluidRow(splitLayout(cellWidths = c("50%", "50%"), 
                    plotOutput(outputId = 'plotYears'),
                    plotOutput(outputId = 'citeYears')  
                    )
                )
    )
)
# Define server logic
server <- function(input, output){
    output$table <- renderTable({
            df
    })
    output$plotYears <- renderPlot({
        p_years <- ggplot(pubYears, aes(year, n))+
                geom_col(colour="black",fill="#3399CC")+
                scale_x_continuous(name = "Year")+
                scale_y_continuous(name = "No. publications")+
                theme(panel.grid = element_blank(),
                      panel.background = element_rect(colour="#595959", fill = NA),
                      aspect.ratio=1)
        p_years
    })
    output$citeYears <- renderPlot({
        p_cites <- ggplot(citesYear, aes(year, cumulativeCites))+
                geom_line(colour = "#3399CC")+
                geom_point(shape = 21, fill = "#3399CC", colour = "#595959")+
                scale_x_continuous(name = "Year")+
                scale_y_continuous(name = "Total no. citations")+
                theme(panel.grid = element_blank(),
                      panel.background = element_rect(colour="#595959", fill = NA),
                      aspect.ratio=1)
        p_cites
    })
    output$network <- renderPlot({
      
    })
}

# Run the app -----
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

When I run this locally on my system, everything works great. However, when I try to deploy this via the shinyapp.io I get an error page saying:

> An error has occurred
>
> The application failed to start.
>
> exit status 1

When I check the logs on shinyapps.io I can see:

> Warning in get_scholar_resp(url, attempts_left - 1) :
>
> Cannot connect to Google Scholar. Is the ID you provided correct?
>
> Error in auth$h_index : $ operator is invalid for atomic vectors
>
> Calls: local ... tryCatch -> tryCatchList -> tryCatchOne ->
>
> Execution halted

I'm guessing there is some kind of permission problem where Google isn't allowing the web app access? This is referenced by another person here [agbarnett/scholar.shiny](https://github.com/agbarnett/scholar.shiny) and someone else likewise asked about the same problem here [stackoverflow.com/questions/70226796](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70226796/not-able-to-use-scholar-package-in-shinyapps-io).

Comment: this might be a related post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63535190/connect-to-googlesheets-via-shiny-in-r-with-googlesheets4

Comment: I will give it a read and see what I can figure out. Thanks for the pointer!